# .replace() not returning

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm real noob at jQuery, this looks like a simple modification but it's not working. I am just trying to insert _thumb into the filename in a jQuery plugin that is otherwise already working.

```
//working
return '<li class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src') + '" height="75" /></a></li>'; 

//NOT working
return '<li class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src', src.replace('.jpg','_thumb.jpg')) + '" height="75" /></a></li>';
```

Comment: Appears like `src` is `undefined`

Comment: What img tag are you trying to find?  The existing one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you if you check your javascript console or error log it'll say something like `src is undefined`

Try:

```
return '<li class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src').replace('.jpg','_thumb.jpg') + '" height="75" /></a></li>';
```

This is because `.replace()` works on a string, the string object in this case is the `$().find().attr()` object, so you need to execute `.replace()` on that object, as in the example.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I didn't understand it at first until I looked at JB King's example below. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
return '<li class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src').replace('.jpg','_thumb.jpg') + '" height="75" /></a></li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Ish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69818/ish) commented, `src` is undefined. Did you mean something like this?

```
var src = jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src').replace('.jpg','_thumb.jpg');

return '<li class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="' + src + '" height="75" /></a></li>';
```

Comment: Yes, this is another way to do it. I just needed to add .replace() to the object, not to the attribute.

Comment: @mahalie: I think you're confused - my answer is exactly equivalent to the one you accepted. The "object" you're talking about _is_ the attribute. `attr()` returns a string.